# Angular-UI Datepicker min-date setting with another date

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

When user inputs date range using [angular-ui Datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker), I wanna make mindate of `EndDate` set 'StartDate`.

in my view,

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="ev_StartDate"
   ng-model="evStartDate" ng-required="true" is-open="startPop.opened"
   ng-focus="openStart()" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" datepicker-options="startDateOptions" 
   readonly="true">
  <span class="input-group-addon">~</span>
  <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="ev_EndDate" 
   ng-model="evEndDate" ng-required="true" is-open="endPop.opened" 
   ng-focus="openEnd()" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" datepicker-options="endDateOptions" 
   readonly="true">
</div>
```

which directive is right to use?

```
$scope.startDateOptions = {
  showWeeks: false,
  startingDay: 1
};

$scope.setOption = function() {
   ????????
  };

$scope.endDateOptions = {
  showWeeks: false,
  startingDay: 1,
  minDate: ?????
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `min-date` attribute, where you can directly pass in the scope variable of startdate which is `evStartDate`. Add below attribute to End date input element.

```
min-date="evStartDate"
```